# Generating Gaussian distribution of random numbers in C++ using template

Tags: c++, gaussian

I wrote the below code to generate random numbers following the Gaussian distribution using `std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0,2.0);`. In order to check that I have got the right Gaussian distribution, I also wrote the code so that it bins the generated numbers into the file `gaussian.dat`. However, what I see in the file is constant values as :

```
ith_bin   number_of_counts 
-0.12   0
-0.12   0
-0.12   0
-0.12   0
-0.12   0
-0.12   0
-0.12   0
  .     .
  .     .
  .     .
```

Can someone tell me where the problem is ?. This is the code:

```
// normal_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std ;

void gasdev(double& number);

int main(){

    double number,delta;
    int npts=100,ii,i,ibin,maxbin=500 ;
    double histog [250]{} ;

    delta = 10.0/maxbin ;
    for (i=1 ; i<=npts ; ++i) {

        gasdev(number) ;
        ibin = round(number/delta) ;
        if (abs(ibin) < maxbin/2.0) {
            histog[ibin] = histog[ibin] + 1 ;
        }
    }

    ofstream myfile1;
    myfile1.open("gaussian.dat", ios:: trunc) ;

    for (ii=-250; ii<=250; ++ii){
        myfile1 << ibin*delta << "\t" << histog[ibin]/(npts*delta) << "\n";}

    myfile1.close();

 }

void gasdev(double& number){

    double rnd ;

    default_random_engine generator;
    normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

    rnd = distribution(generator);

    number=rnd ;

}
```

Comment: Don't use **local** generator, create one in main and pass it to the function. Similarly to calling `srand` in the loop currently.

Comment: Please dont use the term "C/C++", there is no such language. Especially since in the same sentence you mention features not available in one of the two very different languages.

Comment: The loop `for (ii=-250; ii<=250; ++ii)` is very suspicious as `ii` is not used inside the loop body. Thus, you will write 501 times the same line!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two problems

1. Take the `default_random_engine generator;` outside of `gasdev` so that they do not reset the same seed inside the loop.
2. As others have suggested the loop `for (ii=-250; ii<=250; ++ii)` is writing the same line all the time.